# How to track conversion on a form without confirmation page?

Tags: php, forms, google-analytics, analytics, universal-analytics

I have a landing page with a form to collect name/email/phone number the code is :

```
                        <fieldset id="contact_form">

                    <div id="result"></div>
                        <label for="name"><span>Name :</span><br/> 
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
                        </label>

                        <label for="email"><span>Email : </span><r/> 
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
                        </label>

                        <label for="phone"><span>Phone Number : </span><br/> 
                        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"  />
                        </label>

                        <button class="submit_btn" id="submit_btn">Submit</button>

                    </fieldset>
```

if the form is correctly filed a box appear to confirm the submission. The code of that box is :

```
<div id="hidden" class="confirm_page">
<div class="confirm_logo"><span class="pe-7s-check pe-5x pe-va colored"></span></div>
<div class="confirm_header">Thank you/div>
<div class="confirm_text">
    We will reach out to you very soon.
</div>
```

I would like to track form submission in Google Analytics, set a goal for that event. But all the solutions I found involve a submit or an external page to track.
Can someone know how could I do ?

You can see a demo of the code I am using here : http://pixfort.com/myflat/

Thank you so much for your help,

P.S : It will be great if it track good form submission and left out click on the button when a field is badly filled.

Answer (score 0):

You can fire a [Google Analytics event](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) using the same logic that is used to display the modal upon success. In the demo you linked to, this appears to be in the following block:

```
if(proceed) 
    {
     ...
    }
```

You can then [set up a goal](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032415?hl=en) based on the event you choose to fire and see conversion rates, number of conversions, etc. from there.